# Graph theory, being bipartite.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

My aim is create a graph $5$-regular and also bipartite. Is this a correct graph for my purpose ?
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is 5-regular, as each vertex is connected to 5 others, and it is bipartite.

Comment: Okey i understand thank you !